# How to assign string to TaxonomyFieldValueCollection object?

Tags: 2013, taxonomy, string

holds the multiple values of the taxonomy field. I have a string like `2;#Department 2|c98ce851-88fd-41bc-a013-4a69dd6bae66` and assigning it using `PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs()` but I am not able to see the term stored in it.

My code is:

```
TaxonomyFieldValueCollection newDepartments = null;
TaxonomyFieldValueCollection oldDepartments = properties.ListItem[FieldNames.Department] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection;
string strNewDepartments = Convert.ToString(properties.AfterProperties[FieldNames.Department]);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strNewDepartments))
{
    TaxonomyField deptField = properties.List.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(FieldNames.Department) as TaxonomyField;
    if (deptField != null)
    {
        newDepartments = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(string.Empty);
        newDepartments.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(strNewDepartments);
    }
}
```

I debugged the code and found the strNewDepartments = `2;#Department 2|c98ce851-88fd-41bc-a013-4a69dd6bae66` but when I watched `newDepartments[0].Label` it shows `""` (an empty) value. I writing this code in `ItemUpdating` event receiver of a list that's why I took the string of the field.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for answering Mr.ali Sharepoint.

I got the workaround and found the characters which caused issue.

There was an issue in the string i.e. it has three characters which are `2;#` I removed that and it worked perfectly.

So, my code is:

```
TaxonomyField deptField = properties.List.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(FieldNames.Department) as TaxonomyField;
if (deptField != null)
{
    newDepartments = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(string.Empty);
    string finalString = string.Empty; 
    string[] splitString = strNewDepartments.Split('#');
    if (splitString.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < splitString.Length; i++)
        {
            if (splitString[i].IndexOf('|') > -1)
            {
                finalString += splitString[i];
            }
        }
    }
    newDepartments.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(finalString);
}
```

Hope this helps others too.

Answer (score -1):

do it in the `ItemUpdated` event not `ItemUpdating`!

You can then use the properties before and after to update what you want as you were doing ;)

dont forget to update the item, also avoid never ending loop by setting:

```
this.EventFiringEnabled = false;

listitem.update();

this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
```